# Как вывести переменную в текстовый файл?

Tags: python, файлы, переменные, вывод

Только начал изучать Python и не понимаю как вывести значение переменной в текстовый файл:

```
with open("shelter.txt", "a") as file:
        file.write("\nПлощадь: " s " кв.м.")
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3.7 and later

```
with open("shelter.txt", "a") as file:
        file.write(f"\nПлощадь: {s} кв.м.")
```

## Python 3.6 and older

```
with open("shelter.txt", "a") as file:
        file.write("\nПлощадь:" + s + " кв.м.".form)
```